# TTS dynamic library available

Tags: dll, text-to-speech

I have installed the ScanSoft Isabel voice (RealSpeak2) and I want a library to generate the phrases and reproduce them in my PC.

Is there a Text to Speech dll ready to use? I need a dynamic library callable with a function like speak(), as easy as that. I have heard that a dll can be created using the Microsoft Speech COM but I do not have acces to MSV Studio.